# Multiple where clauses SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm writing this query to check for duplicates, but can't get multiple wheres to work. Syntax error near "," is what I get.

```
private static bool duplicate(Dictionary<TableKey, string> entry)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        // TODO: Make changes to this command when new additions/modifications to the DB structure occur  
        string commandText = @"Select Barcode, FullName, Location, Notes, Category From Inventory " +
                             @"Where Barcode = @barcode, FullName = @fullname, Location = @location, " +
                             @"Notes = @notes, Category = @category";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", entry[TableKey.Barcode]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", entry[TableKey.FullName]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", entry[TableKey.Location]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", entry[TableKey.Notes]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", entry[TableKey.Category]);

        command.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

This is my problem:

```
@"Where Barcode = @barcode, FullName = @fullname, Location = @location, " +
                             @"Notes = @notes, Category = @category";
```

How do I have multiple wheres? I've tried "and" and "AND"

Comment: All the values you are selecting are the sames as what is in your where clause.  How is performing this select statement useful?

Comment: It will help find a duplicate. It will look for similar entries. Is there a better way to do this? Can you point me to it please

Comment: I would recommend looking up some online basic SQL Tutorials try to focus on `WHERE CLAUSE` in regards to knowing when to use `AND || OR`

Comment: `Jeffery Haines` are you not reading the comments / answers I think you will need to brush up on your SQL as well as your understanding on how to formulate a valid sql statement..

Comment: @JeffreyHaines - you want to find duplicates?  ok see below.

Comment: If the data is not sorted in your table also use the `ORDER BY Clause.. read up on SELECT DISTINCT vs SELECT as well` other Key words to read up on are `HAVING, GROUP BY, SELECT COUNT() Method`

Comment: @DJKRAZE - What does sorting have to do with it?

Comment: I'm trying to see if the data I have in "entry" is already in the database.

Comment: if his table comes back in a non sorted order and he wants to see duplicates It has nothing to do with it but at the same time it has something to do with it.. not knowing his table structure and Indexing etc... come on now Hogan.. I am thinking outside of the box don't assume

Comment: If you are trying to check if it's already there then use the `NOT EXIST` Function Jeffery do some google searching it appears that you are seeking a quick answer and not willing to do any research on your part

Comment: start doing some reading to better your understanding here is a great easy to understand article / posting http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19344/how-to-efficiently-check-exists-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Don't be so critical DJ. Interacting with people is quicker but you shouldn't see that as a lack of work ethic. I

Answer (score 3):

This should work just fine.

```
@"Where Barcode = @barcode AND FullName = @fullname AND Location = @location AND " +
      @"Notes = @notes AND Category = @category";
```

Find duplicates

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, * 
From Inventory
GROUP  BY Barcode, FullName, Location, Notes, Category
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

> AND

or

> OR

condition

below is example using AND

```
"Where Barcode = @barcode AND FullName = @fullname AND Location = @location AND " +
                             @"Notes = @notes AND Category = @category";
```